# Azure FrontDoor Rule to Redirect All Subdomains

Tags: azure

I have a rule set to URL redirect specific domain names but I cannot figure out how to use a wildcard to forward all and any subdomains that a user would enter in.

My attempt was this with no luck.

[image]

Comment: When you say no luck, what exactly is not working and whats the error? do you have multiple wildcard rules set up?

Comment: No I do not have multiple wildcards set up. It just takes me to the Azure default Our services aren't available right now

We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you use an asterisk symbol in the condition value for the operator **Contains**:

```
*.example.com
```

However, wildcard expressions are only supported by the **Wildcard** operator and **Request path** conditions ([see documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/rules-match-conditions?tabs=portal&pivots=front-door-standard-premium#properties-11)).

You can use one of the following options to build a condition to catch all subdomains:

> Condition: **Request URL**
>
> Operator: **Contains**
>
> Value: **.example.com**

or

> Condition: **Host name**
>
> Operator: **Contains** or **Ends with**
>
> Value: **.example.com**

For example, this is how the hostname condition should look like:
[image: Hostname condition example]

Comment: This works, however I had to add a custom domain of *.example.com to Azure Frontdoor first for traffic to even get to the condition.

Answer (score 0):

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/rules-match-conditions?tabs=portal&pivots=front-door-standard-premium#request-url) states that the `Request URL` condition includes the protocol in the string matching. So the example from your screenshot would not work as its missing `https://`.

However scrolling down in the manual to the section on [Host name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/rules-match-conditions?tabs=portal&pivots=front-door-standard-premium#host-name) based matching. The shown example of hosting the hostname condition with an `ends with` operator seems to be exactly  what is needed to catch all subdomains. Although it's also worth trying the wildcard solution on the host name match condition.

Comment: Thanks for the response but it didn't work as expected.